# Spring setters/ getters and Mutable Variables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, mutable

Let's propose that I have the following class

```
    Public MyClass{

    Date date;

    //Mutable getters and setters

    public Date getdate(){
    retrurn date;
    }

    public Date setdate(Date date)
    {date = date;}

    //Now immutable setter and Getters 

    public Date getImmutableDate{
    return new Date(date.getDate());
    }

    public void setImmutableDate(Date mydate)
    {
    date = new Date(mydate.getDate());
    }
 }
```

Is it good practice to use mutable getters and setters for Spring or Hibernate Framework  and using Immutable setters and getters for my custom coding. What Im i afraid of is the following:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
//assuming that item date was initalized some how.
Date currentDate = myClass.getdate();
currentDate.setMonth( currentDate.getMonth() + 1 );
```

Now what has happened that I just changed the value of date variable inside myClass object and it might be prime root for bugs in system.

Am I correct? 
Can I use immutable getters and setters for Spring/Hibernate as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you provide a mutable setter and getter, it will eventually be used by people. So that's not a good option.

The question is not particularly related to spring and hibernate, but more to API design. Josh Bloch advises - "minimize mutability". But that means you should use immutable objects, and not create instances each time an object is obtained.

The solution above is to use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)'s [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object, which is immutable.

Comment: So does it mean that I can't use java.lang variables because most of them are mutable? I know that: Boolean, Byte, Character, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short, String are immutable. Sometimes I need Muttable objects especially when I'm mapping many to many relations in Hibernate.

Comment: And why is it bad practice to create instances each time an object o obtained?

Comment: well, it is not always a bad idea, but you have to well define the set of possible states. It is not a problem to create an instance each time (unless your method is called millions of time). But as I said, providing a mutable setter defeats the purpose - someone _will_ use the mutable setter and will get in trouble.

Comment: @Bozho is DateTime supported by Hibernate and / or JPA?

Comment: @seanizer - I'm just mapping type="java.util.Date" as timestamp in Postgresql.

Comment: Sure, but I was asking about the JodaTime version

Comment: @seanizer - yes, there is a custom hibernate Type

Comment: You can also use java.time.LocalDateTime since Java 8.